# Prototype, call. Откуда берется второй undefined?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю прототипы и добавляю к ним методы [`call`, `bind`, `apply`] и столкнулся с такой фичей.
Не понимаю откуда берется `undefined`.
Растолкуйте пожалуйста.

```js
function greet() {
  console.log(`Hello! My name is ${this.name}, I'm ${this.job}`);
}

function Person(name, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.job = job;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  return greet.call(this);
}

const person = new Person('Richard', 'developer');

console.log(person.greet());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас функция greet ничего не возвращает потому что. 
Добавить return и получите, что и ожидали

```js
function greet() {
  return(`Hello! My name is ${this.name}, I'm ${this.job}`);
}

function Person(name, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.job = job;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  return greet.call(this);
}

const person = new Person('Richard', 'developer');

console.log(person.greet());
```

Comment: то есть я не могу использовать `console.log()` в функции ?

Comment: а, я понял, я логирую функцию, в которой есть `console.log` ...
пора идти спать, спасибо большое)

Comment: `Person.prototype.greet = greet;`